Proving that a lambda-system generated from a pi-system is closed under countable union
I am having difficulty finding that lambda(I) is closed under countable unions, where I is a pi-system.
I am trying to prove lambda(I) is closed under countable unions because I need to prove it is a sigma-algebra as a stepping stone to the end of my proof. I already proved closure under compliment and non-emptyness.
I have been trying to use the lambda-system's property of closure under increasing unions, but keep hitting the snag that the increasing limits have to be subsets of one another, not helping much with proving closure of unions more generally.
Any tips or advice? Thank you in advance.
